# Rich text editor in bootstrap return cursor to top position when pressing enter

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a Xpages applications with some rich text fields.
It works on all browsers except for safari. (macbook, iphone, ipad) 
The rich text renders correctly.
You can enter text but when pressing enter a new line is created but the cursor return to the top left position. 
Must be a fault in the CSS but I am not a CSS master..

Anybody an idea?

Running domino 9.0.1 FP5 and latest extension lib.
Here is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Test:" id="test_Label1"
                            for="test1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{applicationScope.test}"
                            id="test1">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table></xp:panel>
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration></xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration>
        </xe:this.configuration>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I saw this happen for quite a while on the XPages Forum when I was using Safari.  Really annoying.  My impression was that is was an issue with the CKEditor that was packaged with XPages.  Are you SURE you're on the latest 9.0.1 FP5?  I thought there was something in there that upgraded ckeditor and fixed it but I could be wrong. The problem did go away from the XPages Forum a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the following CKEditor issue: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/12423

It was marked as fixed in version 4.4.5 of CKEditor. Fix Pack 5 contains CKEditor 4.4.6, so it should be working. But reading the recent comments in the link above it seems some people are hitting this issue again in Safari with recent versions of CKEditor, but it's not 100% consistently reproducable.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling the domino server and all fix packs with latest ext.lib solved the problem !!

Thanks all!